# SlickGrid 2.0 can't change row background color in odd indexes

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

I'm trying to change the background color using this code:

```
  data.getItemMetadata = function (index)
  {
       if (index === 5)
       {
           return  {cssClasses: "Unverified"};
       }      
   }
```

It works perfect as long as the index is even. but with odd indexes it has no effect on the background color (it has effect on the font style). I suspect it has something to do with the zebra effect? (I don't know how to disable that)

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `Unverified` CSS class gets applied, but has no effect because it's specificity is lower than what is defined in `slick-default-theme.css`:

```
.slick-row.odd {
  background: #fafafa;
}
```

Notice that the selector uses a combination of two classes, which is more specific than your single `Unverified` class, hence it takes precedence.

You have two options:

1. Remove the existing rule.
2. Increase the specificity of your rule by adding `.slick-row` and placing it after the existing rule in the document, or by adding `! important` at the end of your style declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Neither of Tin's answers worked for me.

I was using:

```
.slick-row[row$="1"], .slick-row[row$="3"], .slick-row[row$="5"], .slick-row[row$="7"], .slick-row[row$="9"] {
  background: #E2E4FF;
```

}

But adding this to my CSS did:

```
.slick-row.odd {
  background: #E2E4FF;
}
```