# Change Row background Color of SlickGrid Table.

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

How can I change the background color of a Slickgrid table? I didn't find any useful material from internet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found two other stackoverflow questions that deal with background colors for rows:

1. [Unable to set CSS properties for rows in Slickgrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10529686/unable-to-set-css-properties-for-rows-in-slickgrid)
2. [SlickGrid 2.0 can't change row background color in odd indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13344583/slickgrid-2-0-cant-change-row-background-color-in-odd-indexes)

From those question's answers, the answer appears to be to add a `getItemMetadata` function to your data object. This function can then return an object literal, one of its fields being `cssClasses`. So if you define a CSS class named "my-row-class" that sets the background color of a table row, you can add that class to the rows in your Slickgrid using:

```
 data.getItemMetadata = function (index) {
     return { "cssClasses": "my-row-class" };
  };
```